# How to pop up alert when HTTP connection fails on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, http, exception, connection

I want to write some code to handle exceptions when HTTP connection fails. I use the following codes:

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError: (NSError *)error {
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                    initWithTitle: [error localizedDescription]
                    message: [error localizedFailureReason]
                    delegate:nil
                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
    [errorAlert release];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    NSLog (@"Connection Failed with Error");
}
```

But the programme just crashes when the connection fails. How to let the alert pop up without program crash?

Comment: Is this running in the main thread or in a background thread? Manipulating UI* objects in background threads tends to not work. Beyond that, which line does the crash happen on? Use the debugger or move the NSLog line around to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is obviously wrong with your code, you will need to supply more information.

Make sure you have a [breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw`](http://www.corbinstreehouse.com/blog/index.php/2008/08/your-most-important-breakpoint-in-cocoa/) and then run the program under the debugger. Then you can determine on what line the exception is thrown.

A wild guess, but perhaps `[error localizedDescription]` or `[error localizedFailureReason]` is returning `nil`.

Comment: The method 'didFailWithError' didn't even get called when I use a wrong url. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Maybe it is not failing? If you get a response from the server, I *think* that counts as success, even if it is a 404 Not Found response.

Comment: Not faliling with wrong url? Then how to add a warning for wrong url? I mean which method should I use?

Comment: Is your didSucceed code being called? If so, check the HTTP response code, there's a method on the NSURLResponse object.

Comment: I find my problem now. I should wait for 60 seconds of timeout interval to see the alert. Thanks indeed for your help.